# Why is powershell giving an incorrect length of this array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I have read [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692806.aspx) that when we read in the contents of `.txt` file using the `get-content` cmdlet into a variable, it is saved as an Array:

> When Get-Content reads a text file and stashes the contents in a
>   variable, the data is stored as an array, with each line in the file
>   (determined by the presence of a carriage return-linefeed character)
>   representing a single item in the array.

I read in the contents of the text file using `get-content`, and ***`4`*** lines were printed to the powershell console.

Then I read in the contents of the same file into a variable `ips`, and then used the **`ips.length`** as well as **`ips.count`**, ***`7`*** was printed out.

What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but without an [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's hard to diagnose this problem.

Comment: There is a blank line at the top and two at the bottom of your content.  These, plus the four lines of content = count/length 7

Comment: @Tibrogargan Please post that as an answer. I can't upvote your comment due to low votes I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a blank line at the top and two at the bottom of your content. These, plus the four lines of content = count/length 7